# strange ~150ms startup penalty using python setuptools

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools

I've been having a weird 150ms startup penalty using python's setuptools, I've constructed a minimal test case and the problem still exists there:

My project layout for this minimal case is:

```
- setup.py
- setuptest
- - __init__.py
- - __main__.py
```

The setup.py file contains:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name         = 'setuptest',
    version      = '0.1',
    packages     = ['setuptest'],

    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts' : ['setuptest = setuptest.__main__:main']
        } ,
    )
```

The __main__.py file contains simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

def main ():
    print "hai"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Doing this within the project root:

```
 —— — time python2 setuptest
hai

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.017s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Gives me 21 ms total script execution, however, after running `sudo python2 setup.py install` and doing:

```
 —— — time setuptest 
hai

real    0m0.158s
user    0m0.144s
sys     0m0.012s
 —— —
```

Gives me 158ms. This +150s startup delay time is consistent and happens across the board when *I* use setuptools but does not happen with things I installed through the package manager or manually install someone else's project, this leaves me to think I'm obviously doing something very wrongly.

Comment: Does the time change when you wrap the `setup` call inside `setup.py` into an `if __name__`?

Comment: @SergeiLebedev, no, that doesn't seem to change anything, still around 160-170ms for a trivial hello world program.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question and though it is `setup.py` having latency issues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer myself which baffles me but it shows why others are faster. It turns out that even though `setuptools` is recommended as newer and better, it also for some reason adds a humongeous performance penalty, at least on my system that `distutils` does not.

All the packages that did go quickly used `distutils`

Editing the example to:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name         = 'disttest',
    version      = '0.1',
    packages     = ['disttest'],

    scripts      = ['bin/disttest']
    )
```

Where `bin/disttest` is an executable file within the project root which serves as a trivial wrapper around the real program solves the issue entirely. Importing from `distutils.core` instead of `setuptools` is the key it seems. Sadly `distuitls` does not have the convenient entry point mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

well, when you install a software using setuptools, it will generate the executable script in a `bin` directory that will look like:

```
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('<PACKAGE_NAME>', 'console_scripts', '<ENTRY_POINT>')()
    )
```

because `load_entry_point()` will resolve through all packages available in the `sys.path` the more locations and packages you have installed, the longer it will take to build the list, and then look it up.

For more details, we need to have a look at setuptools' `load_entry_point()` implementation:

from [`setuptools.py:load_entry_point()`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pkg_resources/src/33e56f318f5086158de8bb2827acb55db2dbc153/pkg_resources.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#pkg_resources.py-376):

```
def load_entry_point(dist, group, name):
    """Return `name` entry point of `group` for `dist` or raise ImportError"""
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
```

from ['setuptools.py:get_distribution()'](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pkg_resources/src/33e56f318f5086158de8bb2827acb55db2dbc153/pkg_resources.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#pkg_resources.py-368):

```
def get_distribution(dist):
    """Return a current distribution object for a Requirement or string"""
    if isinstance(dist,basestring): dist = Requirement.parse(dist)
    if isinstance(dist,Requirement): dist = get_provider(dist)
    if not isinstance(dist,Distribution):
        raise TypeError("Expected string, Requirement, or Distribution", dist)
    return dist
```

from [`setuptools.py:Distribution.load_entry_point()`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pkg_resources/src/33e56f318f5086158de8bb2827acb55db2dbc153/pkg_resources.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#pkg_resources.py-2561):

```
def load_entry_point(self, group, name):
    """Return the `name` entry point of `group` or raise ImportError"""
    ep = self.get_entry_info(group,name)
    if ep is None:
        raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
    return ep.load()
```

from [`setuptools.py:Distribution.get_entry_info()`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pkg_resources/src/33e56f318f5086158de8bb2827acb55db2dbc153/pkg_resources.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#pkg_resources.py-2580):

```
def get_entry_info(self, group, name):
    """Return the EntryPoint object for `group`+`name`, or ``None``"""
    return self.get_entry_map(group).get(name)
```

and I will leave it there, you can follow up to where it gets expensive. I guess methods within [`Distribution`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pkg_resources/src/33e56f318f5086158de8bb2827acb55db2dbc153/pkg_resources.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#pkg_resources.py-2363) where the mapping is done (like the [`_dep_map`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pkg_resources/src/33e56f318f5086158de8bb2827acb55db2dbc153/pkg_resources.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#pkg_resources.py-2468) property) can be quite expensive when executed.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't explain why all my attempts are taking like 150ms while things I installed from other sources, through the package manager or otherwise which dot he same go in like 20ms

Comment: I'm not sure about how different you're doing both calls. But if I read strictly what you wrote, it might be because the packages are in the current directory, and being first in the `sys.path` it walks through less directories and modules to find it. You might want to try changing the sys.path in your installed executable to point to where your module's sources to check that hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that if you install a project from source using either 'python setup.py install', or 'pip install .' (which create a .egg file) the generated executable script uses pkg_resources, which is slow.

However if you build a binary wheel file first (.whl) and then install the wheel, the generated executable script does not appear to import from pkg_resources and is faster. Picking an arbitrary project as an example, here is the result of installing the cookiecutter project with the two different methods.

https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter

If this project is installed from source using 'python setup.py install', the generated executable script contains the import from pkg_resources (and is slow):

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'cookiecutter==1.5.1','console_scripts','cookiecutter'
__requires__ = 'cookiecutter==1.5.1'
import re
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('cookiecutter==1.5.1', 'console_scripts', 'cookiecutter')()
    )
```

However if a wheel file is built and installed with the following two commands:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
pip install dist/cookiecutter-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

the executable script does not contain an import from pkg_resources (and is faster):

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from cookiecutter.__main__ import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: link isn't enough, please include content in your answer